# Extract list of string into multiple list

Tags: scala, generics

I have a  scala list which looks like:

```
val list = List("2.56.7", "1.34.67")
```

I want a O/P like this:

```
List(List("2", "56", "7"), List("1", "34", "67")
```

I tried the below snippet but didnt work:

```
list.map(_.split("\\."))
```

I want a O/P like this:

```
List(List("2", "5", "6"), List("1", "34", "67")
```

Comment: I don't follow your logic.  Can you better explain the transformation from the initial list into the output you expect?

Comment: i want to unpack all elements based on . so it has to look like [2, 56, 7], [ 1, 34, 67] .  to be precise i want to split based on . for all elem in list]

Comment: I was able to get something working below.  I'm not a Scala person, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working script.  We can try using `map` on the outer list, with a lambda which maps each string to a another map of elements.

```
val list = List("2.56.7", "1.34.67")
val result = list.map(x => x.split("\\.").map(_.trim).toList)

def printList(args: List[_]): Unit = {
  args.foreach(println)
}
printList(result)

List(2, 56, 7)
List(1, 34, 67)
```

Comment: wow fantastic this is what i want. Thanks a lot +1 @Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: sure. Can i apply a sort based on each element of sub-list ?

Comment: What is the new output you want?  Also, if it be very different than your original question, you might want to open a new question.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is almost right, but `split` returns `Array` not `List` so you need to convert the result to `List`.

```
list.map(_.split("\\.").toList)
```